# How to fetch data with react js and show it in material ui catagory tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, fetch-api

I'm fetching data from Mongo DB and implementing it on material UI tabs but. It is applying only to one tab. here is the picture of the output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6I60.png)

here is the code

````
                        <TabContext value={value}>
                            <Box >
                                <TabList onChange={handleChange} aria-label="lab API tabs example">
                                    {cats.map(c => (
                                        <Tab label={c.name} value="1" />
                                    ))}
                                    <Tab label="JavaScript" value="2" />
                                    <Tab label="BlockChain" value="3" />
                                </TabList>
                            </Box>
                            <TabPanel value="1">
                                {Posts.slice(0, visible).map((p) => (
                                    <div className="projectTabContainer">
                                        <Link className="link12" to={`/project/${p._id}`}>
                                            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="" className="image" />
                                            <div className="projectTitle">{p.title}</div>
                                        </Link>
                                        <div className="descri">{p.desc}</div>
                                        <button className="code"><GitHub /><span className="codeStyle">Code</span></button><br />
                                        <hr />
                                    </div>
                                ))}
                                <button className="loadmore" onClick={loadMoreItems}>Load More</button>
                            </TabPanel>```
````

Comment: You need to show more code. Right now you are only showing the JSX. Show us where you fetch the data

Comment: ``` const [cats, setCat] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getCats = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get("/catagories")
            setCat(res.data)
        }
        getCats()
    }, [])
```

Comment: Clean up the original question with all the code and properly formatted. Include the material UI version. Make it easy for people to answer and you'll get a good answer.